# ECDSA | How to determine if a public key `y` value is positive or negative?

Tags: public-key

As we know every x value has two y values which are reversed. Just by having the public key, is there a way to determine which side the `y` value is?

[image]

My first approach was to check if the y value is odd or even but after creating many public keys with different secret keys, I didn't find any pattern to check if the y is on the first half of finite field.

Comment: The fundamental problem is that over a finite field the $xy$-plane is NOT split into two halves by the line $y=0$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen So, there is no algorithm to find if a point `private key` is larger or lower than half of the `p`?

Comment: Depends. If you ask an algebra guy like me, the answer is that in a finite field there is no concept of *larger*. The problem is the following. In math we want an ordering of an arithmetic structure to follow certain rules. Such as *if $a<b$ then for all $c$ we have $a+c<b+c$* and *if $a<b$ and $b<c$ then $a<c$*. If we, in addition require that $0<1$, then we must accept that $1<2$, hence $0<2$, hence ... $0<p-1$, and hence $1<(p-1)+1=p=0$. So we have both $0<1$ and $1<0$, and things look bad.

Comment: (cont'd) Of course, you can try and define *larger* in some way, but then you must give up on some of the usual rules arouns $<$.

Comment: The answer to your question depends on such details. Also, in a finite field $p=0$, so half of $p$ is half of zero, which is equal to zero.

Comment: All, I came here because a version of the question was reasked in [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4497407/11619). Nobody there figured out what the asker really wants to know.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Coordinates $x$ and $y$ are in a finite field (e.g. $\mathbb F_p$), thus there is no cardinal definition of "positive" and "negative".

If we use the drawing's definition, "positive" could be $y\bmod p\le(p-1)/2$, and "negative" $y\bmod p>(p-1)/2$.

Another option is "even" (or "positive") when $(y\bmod p)\bmod 2=0$, "odd" (or "negative") when $(y\bmod p)\bmod 2=1$. That's the criteria [conventionally](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#subsubsection.2.3.) used for point compression.

In both cases, the "sign" (or "parity") is changed by going from $y$ to $-y$, except for $y\bmod n=0$

---

Recall that $u\bmod p$ is uniquely defined as the integer $v$ with $0\le v<p$ and $u-v$ a multiple of $p$. If follows $(-u)\bmod p$ is $0$ when $u\bmod p=0$, and $p-(u\bmod p)$ otherwise.

Comment: So if I have let's say `y^2 = x^3 + 7` and two points such as (6, 6) and (6, 11), How can I determine if (6, 6) y value is on first half of finite field (without private key)?

Base on your answer If I'm not mistaken, The (6, 6) is on first half because `y` is even, But we also have (12, 1) that is on first half but also the `y` value is odd.

Comment: @david: the equation $y^2 = x^3 + 7$ is modulo some $p$ which is public, implicitly part of the public key. $p=17$ in your case, thus $(p-1)/2=8$. By the drawing's definition, $(6,6)$ is positive since $6\le8$, and $(6,11)$ is negative since $11>8$. And by convention used for point compression $(6,6)$ is even/positive since $6$ is even, and $(6,11)$ is odd/negative because $11$ is odd. The two definitions/convention happen to coincide, but that's by chance. Which convention to use depends on context.

Comment: What about (10, 15) and (10, 2)? The first point is on first half on finite field but it's odd and 15 is bigger than 8, Does your approach work on any point?

Comment: @David: read the last two sentence of my above comment again. I don't know why you care about positive/negative, thus can't decide. In doubt, in particular if point compression is not used, I'd use comparison to $(p-1)/2$.